# Unity Console Server

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, game-engine, multiplayer

I have to make the online game as my project at the university.
The game must have

The server and the client of any turn-based game. Implementing the basic principles and rules of the game.
The server keeps a list of connected clients, runs the game, deals
processing and transfer of information. The application server with text-based interface
user concurrent operation. Client GUI

I would like to use Unity3D engine, but do not know if this is feasible.
How to make a console server for unity?

Comment: You might want to check whether you are allowed to simply wrap a third-party implementation or whether you're expecting to write some code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Feasible? yes

Easy, well, it depends of your aproach, but it is completly possible, there exist some people than do it with Node.js

But, if your thing is turn based, then maybie you can do an invention with a webserver (like uniserver for example, or Xamp, or some other Apache / mysql implementation) and, inside unity, use the WWWForm class.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html

Is a little cheaty, but it's maybie the easiest way for testing purposes (in no way you must use it for production of a serious game if you have any decent, fast (for production) and secure aproach to the subject, which this is not.

Cheers